# Switching branches using Ankh, error: "the working copy lock appears to be broken" VS 2008

Tags: svn, branch, ankhsvn

As title says.

Current working copy is fully committed, i go to Subversion > Switch, change the url from the current branch to the trunk, receive a popup that says

Working copy not locked

The working copy lock appears to be broken

Any ideas why?

Comment: Also have a look here about this error: http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2009/12/recovering-a-broken-subversion-working-copy/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and at the end managed to somehow resolve it by **switching the project** inside my solution and not the solution itself.

What I did was:
1. Branch the entire solution
2. Switch the a project inside my solution using the **project's URL** and not the solution's URL.

I am not sure if this is the way to go, but it does the trick for me so I am going with that for now.